# Sort checked rows to bottom

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using google sheets to sort school assignments. I am currently using the below coding to auto-sort the sheet by deadline. I have a checkbox in column F that will mark a row as "0" when it is done (when the box is checked). And "unfinished" when the box is not checked. I would like to include a piece in my auto-sort script that automatically puts rows marked "0" (box is checked) below all rows that are marked unfinished (box is not checked). The code below is all working but I am not sure how to go about adding this feature as I am quite new to coding. Any ideas?

(I've posted this before but it was taken down because it had too little detail, sorry if you saw the first one. This one is better)

```
function autoSort(e){
    
   
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    const ws = ss.getSheetByName("School Assignments")
    const range = ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getLastRow()-1,6)
  
    
    

    range.sort({column: 5, ascending: true })
  
}

function onEdit(e){
    const row = e.range.getRow()
    const column = e.range.getColumn()

    if(!(column === 5 && row >= 2)) return
  autoSort(e)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Sorts checked items in column F to bottom

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "School Assignments" && e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() -1,sh.getLastColumn()).sort({column:6,ascending:true});
  }
}
```

This assume that the checked value is "TRUE" and the unchecked value is "FALSE"

Comment: Is this to add to my code or to replace a part of it? I added it in and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I switched out the "true" to "0" because my checked value is 0 and my unchecked is "Unfinished"